# Yowsup working on normal EC2 instance but not on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-ec2, yowsup

I have developed a micro-service in django to access the yowsup2 library for whatsapp.

Everything works fine on my local environment with the procfile configured correctly.

`web: gunicorn XXXXX.wsgi --workers=1`
After I configured it on heroku.

`heroku local`
also works correctly.

But when I pushed the code to heroku server.
The initialisation code for yowsup gets stuck on

`storing prekeys 100%`

After spending 4 hours I were not able to make it work on heroku.
So switched back to Amazon EC2 Instance and its working like charm on that.

Software stack:
Django
Gunicorn
yowsup2
Django Rest Framework

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be this? https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/issues/332

Comment: Saw this link. It mentioned that number was completely blocked but thats not the case.